# Risk Reduction equation

Tags: probability

If, after a point in time, your risk of an event falls by 50% in 1 year and then by 100% in 15 years, can someone help me with the equation that will look at your risk reduction to date for any given day following the original point in time? For example, level of risk reduction on day 15 or day 60.

THANK YOU.

Comment: There are infinitely many equations that satisfy this requirement. You must give the form of the solution you are after. But these seem like strange numbers. Do you mean that after 15 years, you have zero risk? After this, do you just stay at zero risk? The question is unclear, but if so, this is very nonstandard.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. The situation is that in the beginning, a person is at added risk of a bad outcome. But after a change is made, the risk falls back to normal. For example, you may have 5 times the risk of a heart attack because you smoke. Then you quit. 1 year later, your risk is only 2.5 times that of a non-smoker, and 15 years later, your risk is no longer elevated, compared to a non-smoker. Being able to calculate such a risk, and follow the reduction in added risk, on a day to day basis is what I need to do. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The problem here is that you have not given the form of the solution you're after, so there is no way to give a conclusive answer. A common equation for problems like these is a decaying exponential of the form $R(t)=Ae^{-bt}$, where $t$ is the time elapsed, $A$ is the value of $R$ at $t=0$, and $b$ is a factor controlling how quickly decay occurs. For your example above, you'd have about $R(t)=5e^{-0.693t}$ where $t$ is measured in years. Then you can plug in any $t$ you want. Keep in mind that this never actually reaches $0$; it simply gets very small as time goes on ($R(15)=0.00015 \dots$).

Comment: Also, though, if you want $R$ to represent the risk factor compared to a non-smoker, then you want $R \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$, not $R \to 0$. You really do need to make your question more specific. Otherwise, it will likely get flagged as "unclear what you're asking" (which it is).

Comment: Here's the specific question. Thanks again for being willing to help. 1 yr after quitting smoking, a person's relative risk of a heart attack is cut in half. 15 yrs later, the former smoker's risk has fallen to that of a non-smoker's, i.e., their relative risk is down 100%. I want to be able to tell a person, on d14 or d71 what their reduction in risk is to that point. On d365, it will be 50% reduction. On d180 it might be 38% (a guess). I'm sorry if this is still too vague, & if it is, I'll give up. I need a formula that will tell me the reduction on any given day since their quit date.

Comment: Sorry, this is still too vague that it is unanswerable. There are infinitely many curves (all of them piecewise, which is not very natural anyway) satisfying these conditions.

Comment: I've given an answer to this question making a natural assumption about the form of $R(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no natural, non-piecewise function that behaves this way. There are infinitely many unnatural functions that do. All of that said, the following decaying exponential (a form that is commonly used in problems like these) behaves very similarly to the function you seek:
$$R(t)=1+(A-1)\left(\frac{2}{A-2}+2\right)^{-t}$$
Here, $R(t)$ represents the patient's risk factor (relative to a non-smoker) at time $t$, and $t$ represents the time elapsed (in years) since the patient has quit smoking. $A$ is the risk factor of a patient who has just quit smoking (that is, $R(0)=A$). After one year has elapsed, the risk factor will have been cut in half. After 15 years, it will be only a tiny bit above $1$. Here is a graph of the function for $A=5$, meaning that a smoker is at five times the risk of a non-smoker:

[image]

You can see that $R(0)=5$, $R(1)=2.5$, and $R(15) \approx 1$.